# How can I debug my Qt application?

Tags: qt, gdb

I have to debug something in my Qt application but the stack shows instructions that are not part of my code and I have 3 threads (including main) running.  What is the best way to debug this? DO I need squish? Would you be able to help if I pasted the stacks?

Here is the stack trace of the thread that seems to be in fault:

0   raise   /lib/libc.so.6  0
1   abort   /lib/libc.so.6  0
2   ??  /lib/libc.so.6  0
3   ??  /lib/libc.so.6  0
4   free    /lib/libc.so.6  0
5   ??  /lib/libc.so.6  0
6   tzset   /lib/libc.so.6  0
7   QTime::currentTime()    /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4 0
8   FPSengine::xmitData FPSengine2.cpp  93
9   FPSengine::getData  FPSengine2.cpp  21
10  threadDatalog::run  threaddatalog.cpp   109 
11  ??  /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4 0
12  start_thread    /lib/libpthread.so.0    0
13  clone   /lib/libc.so.6  0
14  ??      0

The abort indicates there was an exception and it seems to always have something to do with calling QTime::currentTime() (which calls tzset). Also the problem is always from a thread made with QtConcurrent::run().  This never happens with the main thread or any of the QThreads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368551/qt-question-can-you-use-the-standard-gdb-debugger-with-qt-executables

Comment: Qt Creator provides a front end to gdb in addition to other IDE features. http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools

Comment: First of all, what is the bug that you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For debugging, I always find excessive print statements, and a lot of coffee and patience help the best.